# Solving the system $x_0=\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_0$, $x_1=\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_0$, $x_2=\cos\theta_2\sin\theta_0$, $x_3=\sin\theta_2\sin\theta_0$

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
x_0=\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_0 \\[4pt]
x_1=\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_0 \\[4pt]
x_2=\cos\theta_2\sin\theta_0 \\[4pt]
x_3=\sin\theta_2\sin\theta_0
\end{cases}
$$

The $x_i$ are known and $\sum_i x_i^2 =1$, while the $\theta_i$ are between -$\pi$ and $\pi$ but not known. How can they be found?

It is easy to get $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ by using $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$, but both depend on $\theta_0$, and I do not know how to continue. I have also tried using SymPy and Wolfram Alpha, but they were not successful.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is it $\theta_0$ or $\theta_3$, edit your question and show your attempts.

Comment: @LionHeart sorry, I fixed the indices

Comment: @user it's easy to get $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ by using $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$, but both depend on $\theta_0$ and I don't know how to continue. I have also tried using SymPy and Wolfram Alpha but were not sucessful.

Comment: @LionHeart do you see anything that might be wrong still? I'm not sure about what steps are you referring to, since I don't know which steps I have to follow to solve it

Comment: @salcc your attempts must be in the question body

Comment: @LionHeart ok, I added the information there too

Comment: Is it a spherical issue ?

Comment: @JeanMarie no, it's for a quantum data loader I'm studying: https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2022-12-22-881/. The equations come up when having to compute the correct parameters to load the data in one of the proposed systems, but the solutions are not shown in the paper.

Comment: The solution must be nonunique. Given one solution, you can add $\pm\pi$ to each $\theta$ value to get another.

Comment: Are you assuming $\sum x_i^2=1?$ If so, please edit your post to mention it.

Comment: Under this hypothesis, I would first choose some $\theta_0$ such that $\cos^2\theta_0=x_0^2+x_1^2$ and $\sin^2\theta_0=x_2^2+x_3^2.$ It is then easy to find the corresponding solutions $(\theta_1,\theta_2).$

Comment: @AnneBauval yes, sorry, I updated the post

Comment: @JeanMarie actually, after looking more into it, the system that comes up from the proposed approach has $x_0=\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_0$ and $x_1=\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_0$. However, the accepted answer (others possibly too) can be easily adapted to solve that system too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $x_0x_2\neq 0$, dividing the second one by the first one and the fourth one by the third one we obtain

$$\tan \theta_1=\frac{x_1}{x_0} \implies \theta_1=\arctan\left(\frac{x_1}{x_0}\right)+k_1\pi$$

$$\tan \theta_2=\frac{x_3}{x_2} \implies \theta_2=\arctan\left(\frac{x_3}{x_2}\right)+k_2\pi$$

then we can plug these values in the equations to obtain the right value for $k_1\in\mathbb Z$, $k_2\in\mathbb Z$ and $\theta_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note
$$
x_0+x_1 = \cos(\theta_1 - \theta_0)
\\
x_0-x_1 = \cos(\theta_1 + \theta_0)
\\
\arccos(x_0+x_1) = \theta_1 - \theta_0
\\
\arccos(x_0-x_1) = \theta_1 + \theta_0
\\
\frac{\arccos(x_0-x_1)+\arccos(x_0+x_1)}{2} = \theta_1
\\
\frac{\arccos(x_0-x_1)-\arccos(x_0+x_1)}{2} = \theta_0
$$
Now we have to adjust for the fact that $\cos$ is not 1-1,
so
perhaps other values of the arccos will also be needed.

Answer (score 0):

$x_0^2 = \cos^2 \theta_1 \cos^2 \theta_0$

$x_1^2 = \sin^2 \theta_1 \cos^2 \theta_0$

$x_0^2 + x_1^2 =(\cos^2 \theta_1 + \sin^2 \theta_1)\cos^2 \theta_0$

$x_0^2 + x_1^2=\cos^2 \theta_0$

$\cos \theta_0 = \mp \sqrt{x_0^2 + x_1^2}$

In general,

$\theta_0 = \mp\arccos (\sqrt{x_0^2 + x_1^2}) +2k\pi$

or

$\theta_0 = \mp\arccos (-\sqrt{x_0^2 + x_1^2})+2k\pi=\pi-(\mp\arccos(\sqrt{x_0^2 + x_1^2}))+2k\pi$

$k \in Z$

Answer (score 0):

First choose some $θ_0$
such that
$$\cos^2θ_0=x_0^2+x_1^2\quad\text{and}\quad\sin^2θ_0=x_2^2+x_3^2.$$
It is then easy to find the corresponding solutions $(θ_1,θ_2),$ such that your four equations are satisfied.